# ant delete line from an xml files

Tags: ant

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
```

...

I wanna delete using ant script, all the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
```

I succeed to delete only `<!DOCTYPE` using:

<

```
replaceregexp >
      <regexp pattern="&lt;DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        &quot;-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN&quot;
        &quot;http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd&quot; &gt;"/>
      <substitution expression=""/>
      <fileset  file="${subproject.build.pre-dist.dir}/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml">

      </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
```

How can I do to delete it all?

Comment: using regular expression to manipulate xml document is very error prone. Use XML Document  and make changes.  Try groovy : http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution :

```
<target name="test" depends ="init">
    <loadfile 
        srcfile="${subproject.build.pre-dist.dir}/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml" 
        property="src.file.head1">
    <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="-1" skip="3"/>
    </filterchain>
    </loadfile>


    <echo  file ="${subproject.build.pre-dist.dir}/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml"
    message="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
        ${src.file.head1}"/>
</target>
```